# Is it feasible to check PDF accessibility using c#?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-hosted-app, provider-hosted-app, console-application

I need to check accessibility for uploaded pdf using any dll or any other way. Is it feasible programmatically using c#.
Accessibility of pdf means pdf contain header or footer and misspelled word in pdf or any image missing all the detail of pdf using c#.